# FastText Unsupervised Training only detects small number of Chinese words

Tags: python, fasttext

I'm using FastText to unsupervised train the model (the `data.train` file is a text file that contains 50,000 lines/1.7 million Chinese characters):

```
import fasttext
model = fasttext.train_unsupervised(input='data.train', model='cbow', dim=300, epoch=10, neg=10, minn=2, minCount=20)
model.save_model('data.bin')
```

The output is as follows:

```
Read 0M words
Number of words:  21
Number of labels: 0
Progress: 100.0% words/sec/thread:  254151 lr:  0.000000 avg.loss:  4.173459 ETA:   0h 0m 0s
```

And the word list is as follows:

```
print(model.words)

['</s>', 'd', 'btw', '=', 'iphone', 'in', 'post', '/', '3', '-']
```

It cannot even detect a Chinese character. However, FastText itself supports Chinese; word vectors are trained and available here: https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/crawl-vectors.html

What did I miss?

---

**Sample Data**

```
我是一個小蘋果
你好嗎？今天天氣很好
我是一個小男孩
我有一部新 iphone
```

I expected that the unsupervised training can identify the words like:

```
天氣
男孩
蘋果
今天
iphone
```

*which means "weather", "boy", "apple", "today".*

Comment: Do you know what character-encoding your `data.train` file uses? Are the lines which include Chinese words already tokenized into words via added spaces? Can you show (edit into your question) some representative lines from `data.train` that include the desired Chinese words?

Comment: The words are not tokenized yet. Maybe I should tokenize the texts before putting the data for unsupervised training.